# Method of Frobenius for $x^2y^{''}+x(1-x)y^{'}-(1-2x)y=0$ about $x_0=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this rather mean looking ODE by Method of Frobenius and could use some help on finding the first linearly independent solution.

$x^2y^{''}+x(1+x)y^{'}-(1-2x)y=0$ about $x_0=0$

The point $x_0=0$ is a regular singular point as the following limits exist,

$p_0=\lim\limits_{x \to 0}[(x)\frac{x(1+x)}{(x^2)}]=1$ and $q_0=\lim\limits_{x \to 0}[(x^2)\frac{-(1-2x)}{(x^2)}]=-1$

The indicial equation will be of the form $r(r-1)+p_0r+q_0$. Substituting in the values of $q_o$ and $q_0$ from above we find,

$r^2-1=0$ with the roots $r=\pm1$ As $r_1-r_2=(1)-(-1)=2$ is a positive integer, we will have our first and second solutions in the form, $y_1=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x)^{n+r^1}$ and $y_2=Cy_1(x)
\ln(x-x_0)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n(x)^{n+r^1}$.

As stated before, I'm having trouble finding the series solution for $y_1$. Here is my work so far,

$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x)^{n+r}$, $y'=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+r)a_n(x)^{n+r-1}$, $y''=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+r)(n+r-1)a_n(x)^{n+r-2}$

Substitute the above series into the given ODE,

$x^2[\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+r)(n+r-1)a_n(x)^{n+r-2}]+(x+x^2)[\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+r)a_n(x)^{n+r-1}]-(1-2x)[\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x)^{n+r}]=0$

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+r)(n+r-1)a_n(x)^{n+r}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+r)a_n(x)^{n+r}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+r)a_n(x)^{n+r+1}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x)^{n+r}+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x)^{n+r+1}=0$

Now shift the index so all series are of $x^k$,

$\sum_{k=r}^\infty k(k-1) a_{k-r}x^k+\sum_{k=r}^\infty k a_{k-r}x^k+\sum_{k=r+1}^\infty (k+1) a_{k-r-1}x^k-\sum_{k=r}^\infty a_{k-r}x^k+2\sum_{k=r+1}^\infty a_{k-r-1}x^k=0$

$\sum_{k=r}^\infty [k(k-1)+k-1]a_{k-r}+\sum_{k=r+1}^\infty [(k+1)+2]a_{k-r-1}x^k=0$

Expand the first summation for $k=r$,

$r(r-1)+r-1]a_0x^r+\sum_{k=r+1}^\infty [k(k-1)+k-1]a_{k-1}x^k+\sum_{k=r+1}^\infty [(k+1)+2]a_{k-r-1}x^k=0$

Choose the largest root $r_1=1$ and further collect the series under one grouping,

$0a_0x^r+\sum_{k=2}^\infty([k(k-1)+k-1]a_{k-1}+[(k+1)+2]a_{k-2})x^r=0$

Now set the coefficients equal to zero to find the recurrence relation,

$[k(k-1)+k-1]a_{k-1}+[(k+1)+2]a_{k-2}=0$, for all $k\geq2$

$a_{k-1}=-\frac {k+3}{k^2-1}a_{k-2}$, for all $k\geq2$

Now this is where I begin to fail in finding the first solution. As I choose values of k, there is no observable pattern for the coefficients of $a$. Could I please receive some help on how to finish this question or identifying where I went wrong?